# Как добавить пробелы внутри строки?

Tags: java

Есть математическое выражение, например, которое приходит в переменную `String expression`. Например, такое выражение `"(2+2)*2"`, и из этого выражения нужно сделать такой вид строки `"( 2 + 2 ) * 2"`. В переменной `expression` может быть любые другие выражения.

Возможно, есть регулярка какая-то, которая может решить мою проблему, или как то по-другому возможно это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте следующим способом:

```java
expression.replaceAll("[-+*/()]", " $0 ").replace("  ", " ").trim()
```

Как это работает:

1. Добавляем пробел до и после каждого математического знака `-`, `+`, `*`, `/`, `(`, и `)`. При необходимости, добавьте свои символы.
2. Удаляем полученные двойные пробелы.
3. Убираем лишние пробелы в начале и в конце строки.

Comment: Огромнейшее спасибо вам!!!))